# Passing arguments to job initialization script

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have multiple jobs and for every job I want to have the same initialization script that sets some things up. I'd like to pass some arguments to the initialization script, but unfortunately the arguments passed using `-ArgumentList` seem to be only accessible in the actual job script.

Here's an example that demonstrates the argument only being accessible in the actual script:

```
function StartJob([ScriptBlock] $script, [string] $name, [ScriptBlock] $initialization_script = $null, $argument = $null)
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $script -Name $name -InitializationScript $initialization_script -ArgumentList $argument | Out-Null
}

[ScriptBlock] $initialization_script =
{
    # The argument given to StartJob should be accessible here
    param($test)
    echo "Test: $test"
}

[ScriptBlock] $actual_script =
{
    param($test)
    echo "Test: $test"
}

StartJob $actual_script "Test job" $initialization_script "Have this string in the `$initialization_script"

@(Get-Job).ForEach({
    # Wait for the job to finish, remove it and output its results
    Write-Host "$($_.Name) results:"
    Receive-Job -Job $_ -Wait -AutoRemoveJob | Write-Host
})
```

How would I be able to be access the arguments passed in the `$initialization_script`?

Comment: I don't think you can. What's the purpose?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have a module that I want to load for all jobs in my working directory, but the new jobs have no idea what's the current working directory. Alternatively I could import the module in all of the scripts themselves, but that doesn't seem like a very clean solution.

Comment: Personal opinion: A wrapper that only saves you `| Out-Null` is a waste. You can copy/paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to pass parameters to initialization scripts. Init scripts are designed to be reusable scripblocks to load known resources. If something can't be defined once, then it's unique to that job's scriptblock and doesn't belong in a init. script. You have a few alternatives:

- If you have a module (`.psm1` and maybe a `.psd1`), then place it in one of the module-folders (see `$env:PSModulePath` for paths) so you could simply write `Import-Module MyImportantModule` in your initialization script.
- If you can't use the solution above, I would add a paramter to the actual script and pass in the path as a regular argument.

  ```
  [ScriptBlock] $actual_script =
  {
      # The argument given to StartJob should be accessible here
      param($test, $ModulePath)

      #Import-Module $ModulePath

      echo "Test: $test"
  }

  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $actual_script -Name "Test job" -ArgumentList "First argument", "c:\mymodule.ps1"
  ```
- Or you could generate the initialization scriptblock in your script so it's dynamic:

  ```
  $ModulePath = "c:\mymodule.ps1"

  $init = @"

  #Import-Module "$ModulePath"
  #Something-Else

  "@

  $initsb = [scriptblock]::Create($init)
  ```

Comment: Module imports or other resource loading are a good reason why one would *want* to pass a value (the outer $PSScriptRoot or cwd, eg.) to the initialization script.. PSModulePath 'works' in the case of modules assuming a global clobber is okay.